# How to get element order information from a lower triangle of a matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 5x5 covariance matrix as below:

```
unique.items <- c(1,2,3,4)
diag <- rep("Free",length(unique.items)+1)
offdiag <- rep("0.0", (length(unique.items)+1)*length(unique.items)/2 )
m <- matrix(NA, ncol = length(diag), nrow = length(diag))
m[lower.tri(m)] <- offdiag
m[upper.tri(m)] <- t(m)[upper.tri(t(m))]
diag(m) <- diag
> m
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]  
[1,] "Free" "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0" 
[2,] "0.0"  "Free" "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0" 
[3,] "0.0"  "0.0"  "Free" "0.0"  "0.0" 
[4,] "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "Free" "0.0" 
[5,] "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "Free"
```

Then, I get the lower triangle by:

```
lower.triangle <- paste(tapply(m[lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE)], 
             row(m)[lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE)], FUN = toString), 
      collapse=",")

> lower.triangle
"Free,
 0.0, Free,
 0.0, 0.0, Free,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Free,
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Free"
```

I need to generate a character variable including a grouping variable as below.

```
group <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

desired output

```
"Equal = (G4, Covariance[2]), (G1, Covariance[2]), (G2, Covariance[2]), (G3, Covariance[2]);
 Equal = (G4, Covariance[5]), (G1, Covariance[5]), (G2, Covariance[5]), (G3, Covariance[5]);
 Equal = (G4, Covariance[9]), (G1, Covariance[9]), (G2, Covariance[9]), (G3, Covariance[9]);
 Equal = (G4, Covariance[14]), (G1, Covariance[14]), (G2, Covariance[14]), (G3, Covariance[14]);"
```

G1, G2, G3, and G4 are for grouping. The numbers in `Covariance[#]` are for the order of the diagonal elements in the lower triangle of the matrix.

1. The first (`Free`) element's order is `0` in the `lower.triangle` object. I do not need that in the desired output.
2. The third element's ( `Free`) order number should be then 2 because the order starts with `0`.
3. So the order numbers for the diagonal elements are 2,5,9,14 that need to be in `Covariance[#]`.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I added that object at the top now, sorry.

Comment: Your desired output does not make sense since it is not a valid R statement.

Comment: it is indeed a character value. I had something similar here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63143023/r-manipulation-a-character-vector-for-a-specific-sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the upper triangular matrix to `NA` and get the index of `'Free'` values in `m` omitting `NA` values. Use that index to produce the text that you want using `paste0` and `sprintf`.

```
group <- c(4,1:3)
m[upper.tri(m)] <- NA
inds <- which(na.omit(c(t(m))) == 'Free')[-1] - 1
#first -1 because you want to ignore first 'Free' and 
#second -1 because indexing start from 0 in your case.
inds
#[1]  2  5  9 14

sapply(inds, function(x)paste0('Equal = ', 
         paste0(sprintf('(G%d, Covariance[%d])', group, x), collapse = " , ")))

#[1] "Equal = (G4, Covariance[2]) , (G1, Covariance[2]) , (G2, Covariance[2]) , (G3, Covariance[2])"    
#[2] "Equal = (G4, Covariance[5]) , (G1, Covariance[5]) , (G2, Covariance[5]) , (G3, Covariance[5])"    
#[3] "Equal = (G4, Covariance[9]) , (G1, Covariance[9]) , (G2, Covariance[9]) , (G3, Covariance[9])"    
#[4] "Equal = (G4, Covariance[14]) , (G1, Covariance[14]) , (G2, Covariance[14]) , (G3, Covariance[14])"
```

Comment: I have a similar post, since you helped on this before, could you please take a look at this one as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295192/write-out-a-statement-using-element-orders-from-matrices-for-matching-items-in-r

Answer (score 1):

The data statement above makes a 6x6 matrix, so I edited it to make a 5x5 instead, to replicate what you've got above.  Then, by using the upper triangle, it's actually easier to find the order number of the free elements.

```
unique.items <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
diag <- rep("Free",length(unique.items))
offdiag <- rep("0.0", (length(unique.items)-1)*length(unique.items)/2 )
m <- matrix(NA, ncol = length(diag), nrow = length(diag))
m[lower.tri(m)] <- offdiag
m[upper.tri(m)] <- t(m)[upper.tri(t(m))]
diag(m) <- diag
```

Since you don't want the first element, we could do the following:

```
ut <- m[,-1][upper.tri(m, diag=TRUE)[,-1]]
ut
# [1] "0.0"  "Free" "0.0"  "0.0"  "Free" "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "Free" "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0" 
# [13] "0.0"  "Free"
```

This removes the first column from `m` and then finds the upper triangle of `m`, but cuts the first column of the output off.  Next, just find which observations are `"Free"` and those are the order numbers we're calling `inds`.

```
inds <- which(ut == "Free")
```

We then can define the `group` variable.  We can also define the two pieces of each of the string - the group and the covariance statement.

```
group <- c(1,2,3,4)
eg <- expand.grid(group = paste0("G", group), cov=paste0(" Covariance[", inds, "]"))
head(eg)
#   group            cov
# 1    G1  Covariance[2]
# 2    G2  Covariance[2]
# 3    G3  Covariance[2]
# 4    G4  Covariance[2]
# 5    G1  Covariance[5]
# 6    G2  Covariance[5]
```

Next, we split the data frame based on the `cov` variable, so that all of the same covariance groups are together.

```
eg <- split(eg, eg$cov)
```

`eg` is now a list with four groups, one for each covariance group.

Now, with a bunch of paste statements, we could put all of the pieces together.

```
## collapses all of the pasted statements together by a new-line character \n
out <- paste(
  ## does the paste functions to each element of the list
  sapply(eg, function(x)
    ## puts Equal = and ; around the result below
    paste0("Equal = ", 
      ## pastes the (G#, covariance[#]) together and collapses by a ,
      paste(
        ## makes (G#, covariance[#])
        paste0("(", x$group, ",", x$cov, ")"), 
        collapse=", "), 
       ";")
    ), 
  collapse="\n")
cat(out)
# Equal = (G1, Covariance[2]), (G2, Covariance[2]), (G3, Covariance[2]), (G4, Covariance[2]);
# Equal = (G1, Covariance[5]), (G2, Covariance[5]), (G3, Covariance[5]), (G4, Covariance[5]);
# Equal = (G1, Covariance[9]), (G2, Covariance[9]), (G3, Covariance[9]), (G4, Covariance[9]);
# Equal = (G1, Covariance[14]), (G2, Covariance[14]), (G3, Covariance[14]), (G4, Covariance[14]);
```

Comment: Hi @DaveArmstrong , I have a similar post, since you helped on this before, could you please take a look at this one as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295192/write-out-a-statement-using-element-orders-from-matrices-for-matching-items-in-r